# Pass data from collection view to view controller

Tags: swift

I can not correctly pass data from Collection ViewController  to ViewController. On vc shows the same goods. I do not understand where my mistakes

```
   struct  Goods {
        var goods = [String]()
    }
     var  namesOfGoods = [Goods(goods: ["Good1", "Good2", "Good3"]),
                Goodsl(goods: ["Good4", "Good5", "Good6"]),
                Goods(goods: ["Good7"])]

class ProductsCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "show" {
            var productDetailVC = segue.destination as! DescriptionProductViewController
            let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
            let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
            let product = Goods[(indexPath?.row)!]
            productDetailVC.name = product
        }

    }

class DescriptionProductViewController: UIViewController {


    var name: Goods!

    @IBOutlet weak var productIamge: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nameLabel.text = name.joined(separator: "")

    }
```

Comment: Can you show your didSelectItemAt implementation?

Comment: Well, OP seems to rather leave this platform than show needed code. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a struct not an array.
change this line:

```
nameLabel.text = name.joined(separator: "")
```

to:

```
nameLabel.text = name.goods.joined(separator: "")
```

Also `name` is very bad variable name for this case you should consider to rename it.